The diagonal is not measurable in the product of a discrete and a countable-cocountable measurable space
Relevance: I'm interested in semantics of probabilistic programming languages. In A Convenient Category for Higher-Order Probability Theory, a Quasi-Borel-Space is defined, which is useful because its cartesian closed, and it references some older paper that states that the category of measurable spaces is not useful, because its not cartesian closed. I understand the argument (cartesian closure = first-class & higher-order functions), but I don't understand why the category of Measurable spaces is not cartesian closed.
Question:
I found a proof (Mathoverflow and Isabelle) that measurable spaces are not cartesian closed, which sounds reasonable, but it crucually relies on the following lemma:

Let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{P} \mathbb{R})$ be the discrete measurable space over the reals, and $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{C})$ be the countable-cocountable measurable space over the reals.
The diagonal $\{(r, r) ∣ r ∈ R\} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R} × \mathbb{R})$ is not a measurable subset of the product space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{P}\mathbb{R}) × (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{C})$.

I'm not sure I understand why this lemma is true.
Ideas: As far as i know the product measurable space is defined as the smallest space that is closed under complement, countable intersection and countable union, and the product of the sets considered measurable in the respective measurable spaces it is a product of.
I would assume therefore that a proof could proceed as follows: define a space that is closed under complement, countable intersection and countable union, and the product of the measurable spaces. Show that this space does not contain the diagonal. As the actual product measurable space is the smallest, it can only be smaller, hence the diagonal is definitely not part of the actual product measurable space either.
I searched the internet and found an exercise which has a proof sketch (§2.21, at the end), but i don't quite understand that one either. (Maybe I'm missing some general strategies how measurability of sets in a product space are proved/disproved.)

I have posted a detailed answer, explaining the typical strategy to prove this kind of result and then applying it step by step (and proving each step).  For this particular result you are asking for, I don't think we could defined a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ much better  than the one I defined.  Please, let me know if you have any questions related to my answer.

Hint/Proof outline: Consider the following collection of sets,
$$\mathcal{A} = \{A \cup B \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}: A \subset \mathbb{R} \times C \text{ with }C \subset \mathbb{R} \text{ countable, }B = X \times D \text{ with }X \subset \mathbb{R} \text{ arbitrary and }D \subset \mathbb{R} \text{ cocountable}\}$$
One can show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains products of measurable sets, i.e., all sets of the form $X \times C$ with $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary and $C \subset \mathbb{R}$ either countable or cocountable. Thus, the product $\sigma$-algebra is contained in $\mathcal{A}$. (In fact, putting in slightly more work, you can check that the product $\sigma$-algebra is exactly $\mathcal{A}$.) It is not hard to show, based the on the definition of $\mathcal{A}$, that the diagonal is not contained in $\mathcal{A}$.

@Ramiro The $\mathcal{A}$ you defined is literally the same thing - your $E_B$ is just my $D$ and my $C$ is just $E_B^c$. It’s really not that hard to see.

Yes, you are  right. At first, I had not notice that. In fact, I got to my definition of $\mathcal{A}$ by a different reasoning.

@Ramiro I can see that. But, yeah, your way of defining $\mathcal{A}$ is quite good. I do find my version to be more intuitive, but I wrote down the definition, so of course that’s the case for me. The OP might end up finding either to be clearer.

Did you define A to contain the countables on the right, and B to contain the discretes on the left; and further filled in the remaining unknowns by making A the complement of B?

@drcicero I’m not sure what you meant? Which part of the proof are you referring to?

You would like to prove:

Let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{P} \mathbb{R})$ be the discrete measurable space over the reals, and $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{C})$ be the countable-cocountable measurable space over $\mathbb{R}$.
The diagonal $\{(r, r) \; | \; r \in \mathbb{R}\} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$ is not a measurable subset of the product space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{P}\mathbb{R}) \times (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{C})$.

Proof: Let $\Delta= \{(r, r) \; | \; r \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and let us denote the product $\sigma$-algebra by $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathcal{C}$.
We want to prove that $\Delta \notin \mathcal{P}\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathcal{C}$. A typical strategy is to define a larger $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ that contains $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathcal{C}$, but for which it is easier to prove that $\Delta \notin \mathcal{A}$. It is the path we are going to use in this proof.
Let us define
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{A}= \{ B \subseteq \Bbb R^2 \; | \; \exists \; E_B \subseteq \Bbb R & \text{ co-countable (in $\Bbb R$) such that } \\ &\forall x \in \Bbb R, \text{ if } B \cap (\{x\} \times E_B) \neq \emptyset \text{ then } \{x\} \times E_B \subseteq B\} 
\end{align*}
Let us prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.
$1$. $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$. In fact, just take $E_\emptyset$ to be any co-countable set. Then $\forall x \in \Bbb R, \emptyset \cap (\{x\} \times E_\emptyset) = \emptyset$, and it follows trivially  that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$.
$2$. If $B \in \mathcal{A}$, then, for all $x \in \Bbb R$, we have that,
if  $B^c \cap (\{x\} \times E_B) \neq \emptyset$ then $\{x\} \times E_B \not \subseteq B$. Since $B \in \mathcal{A} $, we have that $B \cap (\{x\} \times E_B) = \emptyset$, which means that $\{x\} \times E_B \subseteq B^c$. So $B^c \in \mathcal{A} $.
$3$. Let $\{B_i\}_{i \in \Bbb N}$ such that, for all $i \in \Bbb N$, $B_i \in \mathcal{A}$. Let $E = \bigcap_i E_{B_i}$. Then, $E$ is co-countable in $\Bbb R$ and, if   $(\bigcup_i B_i) \cap (\{x\} \times E) \neq \emptyset$, then there is $j$ such that $B_j \cap  (\{x\} \times E) \neq \emptyset$. But $B_j \cap  (\{x\} \times E) \subseteq B_j \cap  (\{x\} \times E_{B_j})$. So, we have $B_j \cap  (\{x\} \times E_{B_j}) \neq \emptyset$ and so
$$
\{x\} \times E \subseteq \{x\} \times E_{B_j} \subseteq B_j \subseteq \bigcup_i B_i
$$
So $\bigcup_i B_i \in \mathcal{A}$.
So we have proved that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.
Now, let us now prove that the product $\sigma$-algebra  $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathcal{C}$ is contained in $\mathcal{A}$, that is $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$.
Let $C \times D$ be a rectangle where $C \in \mathcal{P}\mathbb{R}$ and $D \in \mathcal{C}$. We have two cases:
Case 1: If $D$ is countable, take $E = \Bbb R \setminus D$. Then $E$ is co-countable in $\Bbb R$, and, for all $x \in \Bbb R$, $(C \times D) \cap (\{x\} \times E) = \emptyset$. So, $C \times D \in \mathcal{A}$.
Case 2: If $D$ is co-countable  in $\Bbb R$, take $E = D$. Then $E$ is co-countable in $\Bbb R$, and, for all $x \in \Bbb R$, if $(C \times D) \cap (\{x\} \times E) \neq \emptyset$, then $x \in C$ and $\{x\} \times E \subseteq C \times D$. So, $C \times D \in \mathcal{A}$.
So, we have
$$
\{ C \times D \; |\; C \in \mathcal{P}\mathbb{R} \text{ and } D \in \mathcal{C} \} \subseteq \mathcal{A}
$$
Since $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we have
$$
\mathcal{P}\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathcal{C} = \sigma(\{ C \times D \; |\; C \in \mathcal{P}\mathbb{R} \text{ and } D \in \mathcal{C} \}) \subseteq \mathcal{A}
$$
Now, it remains to show that $\Delta \notin \mathcal{A}$. Given any $E$ co-countable in $\Bbb R$, choose $e \in E$. Then, $\Delta \cap (\{e\} \times E) = \{(e,e)\} \neq \emptyset $ and  $\{e\} \times E \nsubseteq \Delta$. So, $\Delta \notin \mathcal{A}$.
Since $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$, it follows immediately that $\Delta \notin \mathcal{P}\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathcal{C}$.
